# Quickly figure out the MAX of the LOWER-bound of a TSTZRANGE column

Tags: postgresql

On Postgres 9.6 is there a way to optimize the following query on a `TSTZRANGE` col?

```
SELECT MAX(LOWER(date_range)) FROM tbl;
```

which takes ~5 seconds on a 26M rows table.

I've tried adding an expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_expr_idx ON tbl((LOWER(date_range)) timestamptz_ops);
```

But that does not seem to get used:

```
Aggregate  (cost=775505.00..775505.01 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..644984.00 rows=26104200 width=22)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `date_range`? If yes you could try: `select lower(date_range) from tbl order by date_range desc limit 1` - not sure how that works out with overlapping ranges though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name — yup, a GIST one. That does also result in a sequential scan of the table, however.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. What if you `SET enable_seqscan = off` before the query? Can you come up with a complete reproducible test case?

Comment: With a regular btree Index Postgres uses an "Index Scan Backwards" for me: https://explain.depesz.com/s/89kC (5 million rows)

Comment: Hm. When I run with `SET enable_seqscan = off` it uses another composite index that consists of two other columns — which ends up slower.

Comment: I will try and come up with a repro later

Comment: The index you have show (`tbl((LOWER(date_range)) timestamptz_ops)` is also used when I test it

Comment: The plot tickens: it suddenly started picking up that index, seeing the "Index Scan Backwards" on the expression index.